# How to get all public posts of a set of Facebook users using real-time APIs

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm creating a service that needs to get all the public posts of a set of facebook users in real-time. The size of the set is variable and might grow a lot, let's say up to 500. All those users know me and are willing to authorize me (somehow) to read their data.

I've done something similar with twitter, it was really easy, I just followed all the users in the set, and used the streaming APIs to listen to updates on my twitter account.

I'm trying to do the same for facebook but the documentation confuses me and I can't understand the best way to do it. I don't think I can do it with just one subscription to the real-time APIs using my facebook account. I think that I might need to obtain a long-term access token for each user in the set, and then make a real-time API subscription for each of them. Is this the way to go? It seems over complicated to me.

To clarify things, I only need to read public posts, but I need to read them all, not just those that facebook think I might be interested in. I do not need to do anything on behalf of the users. The service will be always running and need to receive posts as soon as they are created, polling is not an option.

Comment: When you set up real-time updates for the user/feed connection in your app, then you will get those for all users that grant your app permission to read their posts (`user_posts`).

Comment: @CBroe ahh... that's exactly the part that I failed to understand, thanks, if you want to write a small answer I'll accept it. If you don't, (to leave something useful to future readers) I'll answer my own question in 7 days from now.